# TYPO3 9.5 pages_language_overlay error after upgrade

Tags: typo3-9.x

We updated a working TYPO3 8.7.17 to 9.5, made all necessary steps in the Update Wizards, cleared all caches and yet receive this error in the frontend (backend works fine):

> There is no entry in the $TCA array for the table
>   "pages_language_overlay". This means that the function enableFields()
>   is called with an invalid table name as argument.

Error is called in `/html/typo3/typo3_src-9.5.0/typo3/sysext/frontend/Classes/Page/PageRepository.php line 1588`

Since 9.5 LTS is only a few days old, I could not find anything helpful anywhere else, except for the entry wiki entry covering the error `#1283790586 InvalidArgumentException`. But that does not apply to our project.

Anybody who has had this error after upgrading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table "pages_language_overlay" does not exist anymore. The records are merged into the pages table. You can find more information about it in the notes:

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/Changelog/9.0/Important-82445-MigratePagesLanguageOverlayIntoPages.html

Perhaps you have an activated extension, which uses the old table explicitly (perhaps an old pi based extension). Try to disable your extensions and enable them step by step to find out which extension throws the error. If you found out which extension throws the error you can dig deeper into it.

Comment: Indeed, both fluidepages and vhs use these tables names. I paid no attention to these extensions, since both are labelled as 9.5 compatible. Thanks for the hint.